# Solr data import multi-valued field into a single valued field

Tags: solr, multivalue

I have a multi-valued field

```
<arr name="colors">
<str>Blue</str>
<str>Red</str>
<str>Orange</str>
<str>Pink</str>
<str>Violet</str>
</arr>
```

Filled like this:

```
<entity name="pub_attributes" query=" SELECT name [description] FROM dbo.Colors">
       <field name="colors" column="description" />
</entity>
```

And I need another field with all the colors but only in one line separated by white spaces like

```
<str name="Colors_All">Bue Red Orange Pink Violet</str>
```

How can I do this without accessing the Colors table all over again??
Maybe something like this

```
<entity name="Properites_all" query="
    DECLARE @all VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @all = ''    
    Select @all = @all + ... from '${pub_attributes.colors}' 

    UNION
    Another SELECT that will add more info than just the colors
">
    <field name="colors_all" column="description" />
</entity>
```

Comment: Could you please accept some more answers you previously got ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you looking for is copyfield:
[copyfield wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) and also you can take a look here:[how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596075/how-to-use-solr-copyfield-directive)
Hope that will help.

Comment: I tried that but copying from a multi-valued to a single-valued is not working, plus, I need to add extra info to the field "Colors_All", thats why I need to reference the "colors" attribute in the query so after that I can add more words to it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case, if you use DIH (Data importer handler) for import, you can use scriptTransformer at import/index time: [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer)