# How to keep two versions of a term while indexing in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I want to keep two versions of the words in my Solr index. First one is with AsciiFolding applied, second is without AsciiFolding applied.

So for example if the user typed:

```
gru
```

I want to suggest back

```
grün
```

AsciiFolding is converting the umlauts to (a, u, o) and I want to keep using the original words. So if the user typed:

```
grü
```

I'm unable to suggest the real and original word which it is totally not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use 2 fields, say, `text_original` and `text_ascii`, apply AsciiFolding to one of them only and then use [`copyField`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596075/how-to-use-solr-copyfield-directive) directive to copy both results to a common field `text`.

Note, however, that this will duplicate all other words too. Alternatively, you can rewrite AsciiFolding to insert both versions of the word into a token stream (this is how synonym search work, IIRC "Lucene in Action" had a nice explanation of the process).