# Solr multivalued field - Similar facet field

Tags: solr

Background, I am doing some key phrase extraction on some documents. Here I have a list of terms that I want to use as facets for documents uploaded ([I did this](http://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/06/27/poor-mans-entity-extraction-with-solr/))
So I have a list of terms for colon cancer and an issue comes up where the facet states that there are 10 documents that have a particular term but I get 400 documents, 10 of which actually contain the term and the other 390 do not. I believe it is because the term in particular contains another term.

Term I am looking for: `no evidence`
There is another term that actually comes up 400 times: `no`
Similarly I am looking for the term: `free of` which appears 1 time in all of the documents, but I get 31 results. There is a term `free` which shows up 31 times.

Here is my schema:

```
<field name="ColonCancer" type="ColonCancer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
   termPositions="true"
   termVectors="true"
   termOffsets="true"/>
<fieldType name="ColonCancer" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
<analyzer>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"
            minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
            outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"
    />
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
            words="prefLabels_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there a way to have it behave in a way where I see only the correct amount (no evidence shows only 10 results).

EDIT: This seems to give what I want:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Cytokine/tvrh?q=%22no%22%20OR%20%22no%20evidence%22&fq=ColonCancer:no&fq=ColonCancer:no%20evidence&tv=true&tv.offsets=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this in multiple ways.

You can change the field to a string field. This would turn the facet queries behavior into "specific". That is - looking for "no evidence" would only find "no evidence" - case sensitive.

Another option is to use facet queries - when looking for particular combinations. 
You can then use ~ simbol to force a range between them.

Example:

```
<field name="ColonCancer" type="ColonCancer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
termPositions="true"
termVectors="true"
termOffsets="true"/>
```

```
 <fieldType name="ColonCancerString" class="solr.StringField">

<analyzer>
 <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"
        minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
        outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"
/>
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"     synonyms="synonyms_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"   tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
        words="prefLabels_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <copyField source="ColonCancer" dest="ColonCancerString"/>
```

Here I've added another field called ColonCancerString that should hold the same text - but as string.

The copyFIeld line in the schema tells it to copy the field value.

See here for copy field thread:

[How to use SOLR copyField directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596075/how-to-use-solr-copyfield-directive)

Comment: Can you show how I can turn it into a string field (currently it is tokenized)